# How to mock base template class variable?

Tags: c++, googletest

I am using google test for adding couple of unit tests in the program(C++). One of the class is using the member variable of the base template class.

For example:

```
template <typename foo>
class bar : public foo
{
    // let's say foo has a member variable alpha
    // using foo::alpha in bar
};
```

Now, for testing the bar class, I am mocking the foo class to be passed to bar. I mocked the functions of `foo` fine, but not sure how to handle the variables used from the base class? Like here I'm using the `alpha` variable.

For example:

```
struct Mockfoo
{
    // Mock Methods here
    // Not sure about variables??
};

bar<Mockfoo> b;
```

I am new to gtest/gmock. Have you encountered such cases and how to handle it? I am only interested in checking the behaviour of the function calls, so just wanted to somehow bypass the variable dependency.

**Note:** The variables are kind of complex, they need a couple of objects to initialize it, that means I need to mock them too. So, I am more biased towards some way of bypassing it.

Comment: Mock classes are regular classes, you can add any member you like to them. And you can test them as usual with `EXPECT_EQ` or set them in actions. Just beware of testing implementation rather than behaviour of the class.

Comment: You say that variables are too complex to use directly. That starts to smell of bad design. Why do you use inheritance over composition? Why are `bar` and `foo` so tightly coupled that it's difficult to mock `foo`? Maybe you shouldn't actually mock `foo` (because inheritance is justified) and instead write tests for functionality offered by `foo` and then anything else that `bar` does but isn't covered in `fooTest`?

Comment: Not sure how to help you, given only the example code in the question. If you need to check if `Bar` is calling the correct interfaces, just write `struct MockFoo { MOCK_METHOD( ... ); (etc ...) };` and test it with `EXPECT_CALL`s. You can configure default mocked methods behaviors (like returning some objects) with `ON_CALL`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit odd (but doable) that you are testing a class `bar` and you want to mock its parent class `foo`. Ideally you want to keep your class-under-test and mocked [collaborator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vxCH4AuVRgo&t=154s) classes separate.

If you want to do this, when you mock `foo`, you can mock `alpha` without the need for other objects. Say `foo` is originally defined as:

```
// Real foo used in production
struct foo {
  // Initializing alpha using other objects
  foo(OtherClass1 o1, OtherClass2 o2) : alpha(o1, o2) {}
  int SomeFunction() { return 0; }
  ComplexVariable alpha;
};
```

Then your mocked `foo` can be:

```
// Mocked complex variable
struct MockedComplexVariable {
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD(int, get, (), ());
};

struct Mockfoo {
  // Mock Methods here
  // Not sure about variables??
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD(int, SomeFunction, (), ());
  MockedComplexVariable alpha;  // ---> Doesn't need other objects!
};
```

Here is the complete example:

```
using ::testing::Return;

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Real classes used in production
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
class OtherClass1 {
  //...
};

class OtherClass2 {
  //...
};

class ComplexVariable {
 public:
  ComplexVariable(OtherClass1 o1, OtherClass2 o2) {}
  //...
};

// Real foo used in production
struct foo {
  // Initializing alpha using other objects
  foo(OtherClass1 o1, OtherClass2 o2) : alpha(o1, o2) {}
  int SomeFunction() { return 0; }
  ComplexVariable alpha;
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Mocked classes used in test
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Mocked complex variable
struct MockedComplexVariable {
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD(int, get, (), ());
};

struct Mockfoo {
  // Mock Methods here
  // Not sure about variables??
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD(int, SomeFunction, (), ());
  MockedComplexVariable alpha;  // ----> Doesn't need other objects!
};

template <typename foo>
class bar : public foo {
 public:
  // let's say foo has a member variable alpha
  // using foo::alpha in bar
  int UsingAlpha() { return foo::alpha.get() + foo::SomeFunction(); }
};

TEST(TestFoo, UsingAlpha) {
  bar<Mockfoo> b;
  EXPECT_CALL(b, SomeFunction()).WillOnce(Return(1)).WillOnce(Return(2));
  EXPECT_CALL(b.alpha, get()).WillOnce(Return(10)).WillOnce(Return(20));

  EXPECT_EQ(b.UsingAlpha(), 11);
  EXPECT_EQ(b.UsingAlpha(), 22);
}
```

Live example: https://godbolt.org/z/bs8PEWxxb